# Auto generate doctest output with Sphinx extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest

I think I am missing something about the sphinx extension for doctest.

The typical example in the documentation is:

```
.. doctest::

   >>> print 1
   1
```

Isn't there a way to let sphinx generate the output (here: `1`) automatically?

As far as I understood, it is possible to run:

```
$ make doctest
```

which has the effect to test the code snippets, and compare the real output with the expected output. For example, if you have

```
.. doctest::

   >>> print 1
   3
```

doctest will warn you that it got `1` while it was expecting `3`.

Instead, I would like sphinx to insert the real output alone in my docstring or in my .rst file. For example, if we have something like:

```
.. doctest::

    >>> print 1
    >>> print [2*x for x in range(3)]
```

I would like that when we run `make doctest` with an option, it changes the docstring to:

```
.. doctest::

   >>> print 1
   1
   >>> print [2*x for x in range(3)]
   [0,2,4]
```

I'm sure it's possible, and would be very convenient!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have to strongly (but kindly) **advise against** what you're trying to do.

What you're asking is against the "test part" of the [doctest module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/doctest.html):

> The doctest module searches for pieces of text that look like interactive Python sessions, and then executes those sessions to verify that they work exactly as shown.

These tests have a reasons to be if *you* write the input and the expected output and let Python check if the expected output match the actual output.

If you let Python produce the expected output, well.. it will no longer be *expected* (by the user/author), so the doctests will never fail, hence those tests will be useless.

**Note:** If inside a function there's no logic (if/else, while-loops, appends, etc..) there's no need to test them. And tests must not reproduce the testing logic, otherwise they're not testing the function anymore.

I found [this video](http://osherove.com/videos/2009/8/25/understanding-test-driven-development.html) about test driven development very interesting, maybe it could be of interest to you if you want to know more about this argument.

Comment: Thanks ! I realize I was misunderstanding the purpose of this sphinx extension. I thouhght it was more a way to write the doc in a faster way, but now I understand the whole idea behind doctest.

Comment: The OP's request was very reasonable, and is a common feature in most input-output test frameworks (usually called 'accepting' the output of a test).  Note that the OP requested a way to update *source* files (docstrings in Python programs and doctest blocks in Sphinx), not the outputs generated by Sphinx (HTML or LaTeX).  This would be very useful to have as a way to automatically update outdated tests and examples.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a suggestion on how you could achieve what I suspect you might be looking for:

Doug Hellmann has written an interesting article called [Writing Technical Documentation with Sphinx, Paver, and Cog](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2009/02/02/writing-technical-documentation-with-sphinx-paver-and-cog/). It has [a section](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2009/02/02/writing-technical-documentation-with-sphinx-paver-and-cog/#capturing-program-output-cog) describing how the [Cog](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/) tool can be used to automatically run code examples and capture the output for inclusion in Sphinx-built documentation.

---

There is also a [contributed Sphinx extension called autorun](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autorun/) that can execute code in a special
`runblock` directive and attach the output to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available as part of `pytest-accept`, and extension of `pytest`: https://github.com/max-sixty/pytest-accept

Quote:

> pytest-accept is a pytest plugin for automatically updating doctest
> outputs. It runs doctests, observes the generated outputs, and writes
> them to the doctests' documented outputs.
>
> It's designed for a couple of use cases:
>
> - People who work with doctests and don't enjoy manually copying generated outputs from the pytest error log and pasting them into
>   their doctests' documented outputs. pytest-accept does the copying &
>   pasting for you.
> - People who generally find writing tests a bit annoying, and prefer to develop by "running the code and seeing whether it works". This
>   library aims to make testing a joyful part of that development loop.