# Sphinx - ReadTheDocs : how to display full source code ? Automatic code examples outputs ?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx on ReadTheDocs to document a Python package.

My documentation : http://linvpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

My GitHub : https://github.com/LCAV/linvpy

1) How can we display the full source code on ReadTheDocs ? In Numpy there is a link [source] next to each definition which links to the corresponding source code. How can we make that ?

2) Is there a way to make the code examples outputs automatically computed ? For example if I write the following code example in the docstrings :

```
:Example:

>>> 1+2
```

I would like the output, 3, to be automatically computed and displayed on readthedocs. So in the end we have :

```
>>> 1+2
3
```

Without needing to manually run the example and copy-paste the output in the docstrings.

Comment: You might want to try to split this into two if not three questions.

Comment: Item 1: see http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/ext/viewcode.html.

Comment: Item 2: You could use https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src/tip/autorun/README.rst. But I'd suggest using doctest instead, to actually test the output against expected values that you provide. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9809434/407651 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/41131167/407651.