# With sphinx, is it possible to have example code snippets run and output printed as part of the python docstring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I'm new to sphinx and trying to make documentation for a python library. I've seen example snippets displayed in many python documentation(scikit-learn being a great example) and this is something I really would like to have in my documentation.

Is it possible to include code block examples in doc strings, And have sphinx run these codes and generate corresponding outputs on its own? (instead of having me manually enter the expected outputs) If so, Could you show me some examples of the proper syntax?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9809434/407651

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. The ["top" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9810040/6135182) is not actually an answer, but an explanation about `doctest`. However, the question at hand is not about testing, but about automatically generating and displaying the output of code snippets within sphinx documentation. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9828743/6135182) attempts answering this, but is way old (2012), didn't work for me, and I feel like there must be a better answer nowadays. Therefore, I suggest removing the misleading `doctest` tag, and reopening this question.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076534/407651?